# Android Development: how to create a basic server for my android app?

Tags: android, server, traffic

I am building android app that connects to an API.

The problem I am running into is the following: the API doesn't let me do more than one request per second, and if I have more than one person doing the search at the same time they might shut down my account.

I am looking how to create a server that is supposed to: 1. control the traffic (whenever needed, wait the necessary time), and 2. simply forward the request.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

you can get a server from goddady.com and connect your application with the server using a page php and api parsing json like Volley

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: read this post : www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/